# Create array for each item to json object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to create a JSON object with array of items
and for each item create array of his brand info.

I need to get this result:

```
Array
    (
      [0] => iphone
             [item_info]
                    [cpu] => cpu_cores
                    [memory] => memory_ram

      [1] => lg
             [item_info]
                    [cpu] => cpu_cores
                    [memory] => memory_ram


      [2] => nokia
             [item_info]
                    [cpu] => cpu_cores
                    [memory] => memory_ram
)
```

Instead, i am getting this result:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => iphone 
    [1] => android 
    [2] => nokia 
    [3] => Array ( [cpu] => cpu_cores [memory] => memory_ram ) 
    [4] => Array ( [cpu] => cpu_cores [memory] => memory_ram ) 
    [5] => Array ( [cpu] => cpu_cores [memory] => memory_ram ) 
)
```

The front end is an AJAX with post request to the server.
the object in the front end is called phone_items.

so when i will type in the firebug console phone.items[0].item_info
i will get the CPU and the memory for the item: iphone.

Here is my php script

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

function getAllItems(){

    $items_array = ['iphone', 'android', 'nokia'];

    return $items_array;
}

function getItemsInfo($item){

    $item_info_array = [

        "cpu" => "cpu_cores",
        "memory" => "memory_ram",
    ];

    return $item_info_array;
}

$all_items = getAllItems();

foreach ($all_items as $single_item){

    $item_info = getItemsInfo($single_item);

    array_push($all_items, $item_info);
}

print_r($all_items);

?>
```

Comment: You can't have an array key twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the item info instead of just pushing it onto the array.

Do something like this:

```
foreach ($all_items as $idx => $single_item){
    $all_items[$idx] = [
        'name' => $single_item, 
        'item_info' => getItemsInfo($single_item),
    ];
}
```

Then to echo valid JSON:

```
echo json_encode($all_items);
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact output you want isn't possible because your array elements have two values ("iphone" and also the "item_info" array). However, with a bit of a cleaning we can make something very close:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

function getItemNames() {
    return ['iphone', 'android', 'nokia'];
}

function getItemsInfo($item) {
    return ["cpu" => "cpu_cores", "memory" => "memory_ram"];
}

$allItems = [];
$itemNames = getItemNames();

foreach ($itemNames as $itemName) {
    $info = getItemsInfo($itemName);
    $allItems[] = ['name' => $itemName, 'item_info' => $info];
}

print_r($allItems);
```